# ArcPy map algebra equivalent for "any"?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, map-algebra

I have binary (0-1) rasters.

I'm trying to do an operation equivalent to:

```
z = arcpy.sa.Con((Raster(a) | Raster(b) | Raster(c) | ... | Raster(y))
```

where the raster files a-y are dynamically generated from a list. I tried using python's built-in 'any' function like so:

```
z = arcpy.sa.Con(any(Raster(r) for r in rasters_a_to_y))
```

but to no avail, I get an error `Truth value of a raster is ambiguous`.  Is there any equivalent to '`any`' function in the ArcPy toolbox or another way to do this that I haven't considered?

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Nothing?  Errors?  Something unexpected?

Comment: "Truth value of a raster is ambiguous" error

Comment: you are not testing anything. are all your raster values 0 or 1 ? in this case you could select the maximum

Comment: Yes, they are all binary rasters.

Comment: @triphook in future, can you please edit your questions to add any further info requested by commenters. This is important so all the information is in one place (the question) and potential answerers don't have to dig through a comment trail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could [sum the rasters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) and test whether the total is greater than 0.

```
list_of_rasters = [Raster(a), Raster(b), Raster(c)]
z = CellStatistics(list_of_rasters, "SUM") > 0
```